# Besse, Einstein manifold explanation of a sentence

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying Besse's Einstein manifolds, in particular in chapter 6 I'm not sure I've understand this paragraph:

6.16 If a 3-manifold admit a metric with constant sectional curvature, then its universal covering is diffeomorphic either to the 3-sphere or to $\mathbb{R}^3$. In particular $\pi_2(M)=0$ or any 2-embedded sphere in M bounds a 3-ball embedded in M.

Can someone explain why this implications are true?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space and $\tilde{X}$ its universal covering, then $\pi_n(X) = \pi_n(\tilde{X})$ for all $n \geq 2$. Hint: use the lifting property of continuous functions.

Comment: Ok! So constant sectional curvature implies Universal covering diffepmorphic to.. from Killing Hopf theorem (right?) Then we have the proposition about $\pi_n$ groups. But why study $\pi_2$? I want to use this result for example to prove that $S^1\times S^2$ doesn't admit constant sectional curvature metrics

Comment: What's $\pi_2(S^1\times S^2)$?

Comment: i'd say it's \Bbb{Z}(or anyway it's different from trivial group) my question was, why not take $\pi_1$ for example?

Comment: You cannot calculate $\pi_1$ from the universal cover.

Comment: Right! Thank you for help